# template recursion with many base cases

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, case, radix

The goal is to create a tuple from another tuple (and extract its type) by taking its component at position START and then skipping every INTERVAL components.  No parameter packs are even needed:

```
template <int NUM_LEFT, int START, int INTERVAL>
struct alternating_tuple_helper {
    template <typename TUPLE>
    auto operator() (const TUPLE& t) const
    -> decltype (std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple (std::get<START>(t)), alternating_tuple_helper<NUM_LEFT - INTERVAL, START + INTERVAL, INTERVAL>()(t))) {
        return std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple (std::get<START>(t)), alternating_tuple_helper<NUM_LEFT - INTERVAL, START + INTERVAL, INTERVAL>()(t));
    }
};

template <int START, int INTERVAL>
struct alternating_tuple_helper<0, START, INTERVAL> { // first base case   
    template <typename TUPLE>
    std::tuple<> operator() (const TUPLE& t) const {return std::tuple<>();}
};

template <int START, int INTERVAL>
struct alternating_tuple_helper<-1, START, INTERVAL> { // second base case
    template <typename TUPLE>
    std::tuple<> operator() (const TUPLE& t) const {return std::tuple<>();}
};
```

//  ... base cases must cover 0, -1, -2, ... down to -INTERVAL+1.  How to do that?

```
template <typename TUPLE, int START = 0, int INTERVAL = 2>  // extracting the type
struct alternating_tuple_type {
    using type = decltype (alternating_tuple_helper<std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value - START, START, INTERVAL>()(std::declval<TUPLE>()));
};

template <typename TUPLE, int START = 0, int INTERVAL = 2>  // getting the new tuple itself
typename alternating_tuple_type<TUPLE, START, INTERVAL>::type alternating_tuple (const TUPLE& t) {
    return alternating_tuple_helper<std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value - START, START, INTERVAL>()(t);
}
```

How to handle all the base cases with arbitrary value INTERVAL?  The code works otherwise, and tested for INTERVAL size up to 10 (yes, currently I'm using macros to cover 0, -1, -2, ..., -10, but of course that stinks).

I tried

```
template <int NUM_LEFT, int START, int INTERVAL>
struct alternating_tuple_helper {
    template <typename TUPLE>
        auto operator() (const TUPLE& t) const 
        -> std::conditional<(NUM_LEFT > 0), decltype (std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple (std::get<START>(t)), alternating_tuple_helper<NUM_LEFT - INTERVAL, START + INTERVAL, INTERVAL>()(t))), std::tuple<>> {
            return (NUM_LEFT > 0) ? std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple (std::get<START>(t)), alternating_tuple_helper<NUM_LEFT - INTERVAL, START + INTERVAL, INTERVAL>()(t))
                : std::tuple<>();
    }
};
```

But it won't compile because it clashes with alternating_tuple_type somehow (which is to exract the type).  Perhaps only that part needs to be fixed then.  But I'm not sure what the problem is there exactly.

Comment: Ok, by changing the math a bit (NUM_LEFT - 1 instead of NUM_LEFT - INTERVAL, and (std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value - START - 1) / INTERVAL + 1 instead of std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value - START), I've reduced it to only the 0 base case needed. But I still want to know how to deal with those multiple base cases. There may be situations where there are inevitably (arbitrarily) many base cases to cover.  How to deal with the above many base cases without changing the math like I just mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a logical test using this technique:

```
#include <utility>

template<int n, int m, class=void>
struct count{
  enum{value=1 +count<n-m, m>::value};
};
template<int n, int m>
struct count<n,m, typename std::enable_if<(n<m)>::type>{
  enum{value=0};
};
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/Q4ortu)

To pretty the template signature, you can stick the `void` hack in an implementation detail namespace, and forward the public interface to there.